# How to bring app to foreground from within ForegroundService

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-service

I have a `ForegroundService` that takes a little while to run. In the meantime the user may move to the app to the background while it is running, such as pressing the home button or enter a different app. When the `ForegroundService` reaches a "trigger", it attempts to start a new intent. This works great if the app is in the foreground, but doesn't work if it is in the background. The goal is when a "trigger" is reached, the app will come back to the foreground so the user can provide needed input in the new intent. In an attempt to do so I have added the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as it looked like they would accomplish this. But the app is not brought back to the foreground. Is this something that can be done?

Below is the relevant parts of code in question:

```
MainActivity.kt
...
private fun startService() {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
}
...
```

```
ForegroundService.kt
...
//When trigger is reached, start the new activity and bring app to foreground if it was moved to background
private fun startNewActivity() {
    //First two lines are to shut down the foreground service since it has reached a trigger and is complete.
    super.onDestroy()
    stopSelf()
    //Start the new intent
    val startNewIntent = Intent(this, NewIntent:: class.java)
    startNewIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP //Assumption was these flags would bring app to foreground
    startActivity(startNewIntent)
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using android 10 and above, you will need to request for `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permissions. These can be granted using the following.

```
// Check if the permission is granted
if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    // Permission is granted, start your service
    startService(new Intent(this, FloatingViewService.class));
} else {
    // Permission is not granted, ask the user to enable it
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

// Handle the result of the user's action
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Check if the permission is granted
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // Permission is granted, start your service
            startService(new Intent(this, FloatingViewService.class));
        } else {
            // Permission is denied, show a message
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable overlay permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Comment: Great. This works for me on devices using Android 10 and 12. targetSdkVersion is 33.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the intent be registered into the system, you need to use a [`PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) instead of a normal `Intent`; when the Foreground Service is over (when your trigger is fired), you can send this pending intent using [`send()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send(int)) method

```
ForegroundService.kt
...
//When trigger is reached, start the new activity and bring app to foreground if it was moved to background
private fun startNewActivity() {
    //First two lines are to shut down the foreground service since it has reached a trigger and is complete.
    super.onDestroy()
    stopSelf()
    
    
    //Start the new intent

    val startNewIntent = Intent(this, NewIntent:: class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, startNewIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )
    
    try {
        pendingIntent.send()  // this should start `NewIntent` activity
    } catch (e: CanceledException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }   
    
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I tried to implement this and found that it behaved the same as before. In other words, the app does not come back to the foreground using the `PendingIntent` even though debug logs show that `pendingIntent.send()` is called. I did find [this reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) where it says "the app can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is sent." It sounds like this should work.

Comment: Further more, `pendingIntent.send()` is called, but `onCreate` in NewIntent is not called until I manually bring the app back into focus. This was determined with logging.

Comment: Seems weird.. Can you test it on another device and different API level ... Also maybe you need to send a BroadcastReceiver wrapped with the pending intent.. And do the same cod in onReceive()

Comment: I tested in API v16 and it worked. But testing with API v30 both in the emulator and physical device, it did not work. I wonder if there has been a change blocking this in newer versions? Do you have an example of using a BroadcastReceiver wrapped with the pending intent?

Comment: @Tom there was a change on API level 29 (Android 10), which is outlined in the doc here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts
It outlines a list of conditions, of which one must be met in order to push the app into foreground.